# Where is data folder for Bitcoin Core in Windows 7?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

I cannot find any wallet.dat file on my c: drive. Any ideas where it can be put?
Everybody says the same and I'm doing it. Maybe I'm kind of idiot so I'm pasting screens with steps I have done:

1

[image]

2

[image]

The same with Litecoin Core

Comment: Type literally in your explorer location bar: %APPDATA%\Bitcoin

Comment: I did it many times

Comment: Are you sure you're running Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Any other ideas? It makes me sick :(

Comment: Perhaps you selected another data directory yourself. Bitcoin-Qt asks you what directory to use the first time it is started?

Comment: I don't remeber... But I don't think so....

Comment: @PieterWuille is there a way to check it?

Comment: It seems that the answer is no, but we're working on fixing it: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7732

Comment: So now I cannot import my old keys to new wallet? :o

Answer (score 0):

The default directory would be %APPDATA%\Bitcoin

If you can't find it you may hit the Windows-Key+F and enter "wallet.dat"

You can also export your wallet from within Bitcoin-QT: File>Save Wallet

Comment: I want to import... There must be sth wrong with my Windows configuration. Win+F and search for "wallet.dat" gives me just results with my back-up files. Win+F for "size:gigantic" search for files greater that 128MB. It cannot find the blockchain file also which is greater for sure. Windows sucks ;)

Comment: You don't need to know where your Blockchain and other files are in order to import a new wallet.dat. Although it's very strange that you're unable to find it!【・ヘ・?】

Comment: So how import without wisdom about data folder?

Comment: wallet.dat is only kilobytes big. You should include all files and folders in your search.